# Manipulating items of array of class objects in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

For the code below, I create an array of class objects using a for loop. However, I'm not able to access and modify the objects in the list. What do I have to change to make this work?

```
def main():
    class BankAccount:
        def __init__(self,nameOfCustomer,balanceOfCustomer):
            self.name = nameOfCustomer
            self.balance = balanceOfCustomer
            print "\nNew customer created in system with name " + self.name + " and initial balance of $" + str(self.balance)

        def get_balance(self):
            print "The current balance for " + self.name + " is: $" + str(self.balance)
            return self.balance

        def deposit(self,amount):
            self.balance += amount
            print self.name + " just deposited $" + str(amount)
            return self.balance

        def withdraw(self,amount):
            self.balance -= amount
            print self.name + " just withdrew $" + str(amount)
            return self.balance

    customerList = {"Eric": 10000,
                    "Tom": 20000,
                    "Bill": 25000,
                    "Casey": 40000}

    individualAccountList = []
    for key, value in customerList.iteritems():
        individualAccountList.append(BankAccount(key,customerList[key]))

    for i in individualAccountList:
        print i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "However, I'm not able to access and modify the objects in the list" -- Can you elaborate on this sentence?  What are you trying to do?  In what way is your current code failing?  What did you expect your current code to do that it isn't doing?  etc.

Comment: As a matter of style, the class `BankAccount` should not be defined in `main()`, but at the module scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works:

```py
for i in individualAccountList:
        print i.name
```

gives:

```py
Casey
Bill
Eric
Tom
```

than:

```py
individualAccountList[0].name = "name changed"
print individualAccountList[0].name
>> name changed
```